# Using ortho projection before rendering 2D over 3D

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I want to render a 2D HUD over a 3D scene in OpenGL.

Now, I've looked around, and most people say that before drawing something in 2D, you have to use an orthographic projection before drawing something. But my take on this would be to just write a separate shader program just for the HUD, and just give the coordinates in NDC, so that the vertex shader does almost nothing.

So why does everyone want to multiply the coordinates with an ortho matrix? Is there a downside to what I want to do? Thanks!

Comment: "give the coordinates in NDC" involves multiplying the coordinates by an ortho matrix, or equivalent. Simply "most people around" do that in the vertex shader, or talk about legacy OpenGL where it was the only way of doing that. There aren't real downsides to your approach.

Comment: One advantage of using an ortho matrix is that you can redefine your coordinate system in terms of what you want. As an example, if you wanted to define your HUD (or any GUI element) in terms of pixel coordinates just use an ortho matrix with x bounds of 0 to screen width and y bounds of 0 to screen height. You could apply the same method to transform to  point scaling, centimetres, etc... (these would have to be recomputed during window resize since they are physically based)